# Top-level build folder in multi-module gradle project

Tags: java, gradle

I'm playing around with `gradle`, mostly to explore if its a viable alternative to maven for my builds. I quite like the idea of a more programmatic approach to build configuration, so it's quite promising so far.

However, I do have a couple of minor annoyances I'm trying to wrap my head around. One particular issue is to identify what actually generate the top level build folder in my project, as the top level project doesn't have the java plugin applied.

For example, I got a hierarchy something akin to this:

```
 /POC
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    /subproject1
    /subproject2
```

Now, in my top-level configuration, I'm applying the java plugin *only* to the subprojects, and I can see from the output of `gradle build`, that indeed the build steps are only executed on the subprojects.

However, I still get a build folder in the top level directory, in addition to the build folders in the subprojects.

This isn't a huge deal, but, it tickles my OCD, I want to know why it pops up there. I feel like I'm missing something important in respect to how gradles build lifecycle works.

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file and other config files (btw, it is 'settings.gradle', not setting.gradle). Which version of Gradle are you using?